# No such file or directory after confirming the file exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I have a route on my server used for retrieving files, but it's acting a little problematic. Some times it spits out an error that the file it's trying to retrieve doesn't exist, but the top part of the script confirms the file exists. The error is printed after I've deleted the file, so I guess some part of this asynchronous disgusting mess of a function is checking for a file and not finding it which crashes the server. In a desperate attempt at figuring out where this error occurred, I used Try Catch on everything, but it hasn't helped in discovering where the error occurs. Here is the function:

```
app.get("/upload", function(req, res) {
  var filePath = path.join("/var/www/ip/uploads/", req.header("Project-Number") + "_signed.xlsx")
  //var filePath = path.join("/var/www/ip/uploads/", "3333_signature_projectmanager.jpg")

  // TODO:
  // Low priority: Fix the ugly try catch blocks

  try {
    if (fileSystem.existsSync(filePath)) {
      console.log("File exists: " + filePath)
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("File asked to retrieve not found: " + err)
    return
  }

  console.log("File exists 2: " + filePath)

  try {
  var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath)
  }
  catch {
    console.log("Error creating file variable")
  }
  try {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "image/jpg",
    "Content-Length": stat.size
    //"Project-Number": req.header("Project-Number")
  })
  }
  catch {
    console.log("Error creating response")
  }

  try {
  console.log("Entered the problematic try")
  var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath)
  console.log("Second one in problematic")
  readStream.pipe(res)
  console.log("Last one in problematic")
  }
  catch {
    console.log("Error reading file")
  }


  // Delete the finished file from the server
  try {
    fileSystem.unlinkSync(filePath)
    console.log("File " + req.header("Project-Number") + "_signed.xlsx" + " was retrieved")
  } catch {
    console.error("Error when deleting file: ")
  }

  try {
    delete dict[req.header("Project-Number")]
  }
  catch {
    console.log("Error deleting dict")
  }
})
```

```
0|server  | File exists: /var/www/ip/uploads/333333_signed.xlsx
0|server  | File exists 2: /var/www/ip/uploads/333333_signed.xlsx
0|server  | Entered the problematic try
0|server  | Second one in problematic
0|server  | Last one in problematic
0|server  | File 333333_signed.xlsx was retrieved
0|server  | { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/ip/uploads/333333_signed.xlsx']
0|server  |   errno: -2,
0|server  |   code: 'ENOENT',
0|server  |   syscall: 'open',
0|server  |   path: '/var/www/ip/uploads/333333_signed.xlsx' }
PM2       | App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2       | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2       | App [server:0] online
```

It only really happens when more than one client is retrieving files are roughly the same time. I have also looked in the folder, I can see that the file exists. Any ideas on what causes this error?

Comment: It may happens you are deleting the file after your job done done for the 1'st request where as the 2'nd request accessing the same file. For example step 1) req 1 accessing project1_signed.xls. step 2) req 2 accessing project1_signed.xls. 3) req 1 deleting project1_signed.xls 4) req 2 unable to access your file

Comment: @Richardson.M Good point. I thought I weeded out this problem, but I will do some tests to double check.

Comment: Here is another possible solution
readStream = fs.createWriteStream(destination)
readStream.pipe(res)
readStream.on('end', () => console.log('delete your file here!'))